# How to handle multiple interrupt signals in python?

Tags: python, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

Let's say I have this script with a function to handle my interrupt signal like so:

```
import signal
import time
import sys

def handle_interrupt(signum, frame):
   print('Gracefully exiting in 5 seconds...')
   time.sleep(5)
   sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_interrupt)

print('Sleeping for 5 minutes...')
time.sleep(300)
```

How can I handle a second interrupt signal so that it quits instantly without waiting 5 additional seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to define an interrupt handler object to manage the state of whether the interrupt signal has been received or not already.

```
import signal
import time
import sys

class InterruptHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.interrupted = False

    def handle_signal(self, signum, frame):
        if self.interrupted:
            print("Quitting now!")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Quitting in 1 minute!")
            self.interrupted = True
            time.sleep(60)
            sys.exit()
            

interrupt_handler = InterruptHandler()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, interrupt_handler.handle_signal)


print("Sleeping for 5 minutes...")
time.sleep(300)
print("Done sleeping.")
```

Here's another solution using a global variable to store the "interrupted" state. Using global variables is generally considered bad practice, however.

```
import signal
import time
import sys

def handle_sigint(signum, frame):
    global interrupted
    if interrupted:
        print("Quitting now!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Quitting in 1 minute!")
        interrupted = True
        time.sleep(60)
        sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)
interrupted = False

print("Sleeping for 5 minutes...")
time.sleep(300)
print("Done sleeping.")
```